# When i create a new project generated by angular cli not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

```js
//package.json
{
  "name": "whattodo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

When I create a new project using angular cli and it's not working? Please help me why this error am getting?I tried the solution from GitHub but still am getting this error

vendor.bundle.js:523 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:66)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at webpackJsonpCallback (inline.bundle.js:26)
at main.bundle.js:1
```

inline.bundle.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Repro steps.
I ran `ng new testapp`
then `cd into testapp`
Then `ng serve`
The browser for localhost:4200 shows blank with the afore-mentioned errors

Comment: what is the version of node and angular-cli

Comment: Please be more specific about what you have tried, what you are doing, and what problem you are having.

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: execute `npm install` in working directory and see whether it is resolved or not

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6196  This is the link where we have  solutions for the same problem.I tried all solutions in this but still getting error

Comment: Am using angular/cli: "~1.7.4", and  node v8.11.1

Comment: tried  npm install but still having the error @Vikas